# Can css clip-path expand to dinamically fit and cover the size of its container?

Tags: svg, clip-path

Hi,

I have a clip-path from a SVG image made for a 180x250px container. However, I want to use the same shape for a bigger container. Is it possible to have the SVG expand so it covers the bigger container as well? OR do I have to make yet another svg image to fit the new size?

Thank you.

Comment: use objectBoundingBox units.

Comment: You mean with percentages?